# Button onClick doesn't trigger after adding views dynamically

Tags: android, onclicklistener, buttonclick

There's an EditText in my activity and every time the user presses enter button on the keyboard, using `OnEditorActionListener` another EditText will be added to the LinearLayout.
The problem is after adding those views, the Button onClick doesn't work. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

button `onClick`:

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(NewExpenseActivity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
```

.

```
private TextView.OnEditorActionListener editorActionListener = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
            createNewEditText();
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

.

```
public void createNewEditText() {
        textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(this);
        textInputLayout.setPadding(padding_in_px_16, padding_in_px_8, padding_in_px_16, padding_in_px_8);
        editText = new EditText(NewExpenseActivity.this);
        editText.setId(id);
        editText.setHint("Enter Name");
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        editText.setOnEditorActionListener(editorActionListener);
        editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
        textInputLayout.addView(editText);
        ITEM_MAP.put("Key" + idNum, id);
        idNum++;
        linearEtList.addView(textInputLayout);
    }
```

Comment: try setting setEnabled(true) and setClickable(true)

Comment: Could you share the entire NewExpenseActivity class. It's hard to tell whats going on from what you have provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using :-

```
private TextView.OnEditorActionListener editorActionListener = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if (event != null) {
            createNewEditText();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Because of :-

> **actionId** int: Identifier of the action. This will be either the identifier you supplied, **or EditorInfo#IME_NULL if being called due to the enter key being pressed**.
>
> **event** If triggered by an enter key, this is the event; otherwise, this is null.

[onEditorAction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener#onEditorAction(android.widget.TextView,%20int,%20android.view.KeyEvent))

And the setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) adds/sets the softkeyboard to have a **NEXT** (**`--->|`**) button. Only if that soft button is used will the actionId == IME_ACTION_NEXT.

like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BvjX.png)

If you want both then you can do

```
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT || (event != null &&  event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    addEditText();
                }
                return false;
            }
```